# multiple submission buttons to python flask app

Tags: python, html, flask

I am having a problem getting both of these submissions to work.  I will search with one and it will be successful then when I refresh and try to search with the other one I get a url not found error.  Been fighting                           with this all day thank you for your help

```
    <playlist>
          <input id = "url2" type = "text" name = "url"
   
           placeholder = "Genre">

           <input type = "submit" name = "button" onclick =                      
                "test()">.  

          <script>

             function test() {

             var url2= document.getElementById("url2").value;

             document.write("Generating Playlist");

             setTimeout(function(){window.location=

             "http://127.0.0.1:5000/recommend/genre/"+url2;}, 3000);
                    }
                </script>
```

Sorry I'm new to this I didn't realize I wasn't allowed to post screenshots yet.  I have 2 of these submissions one with /genre and the other with /limit, when they are alone in the code they work but when I have both of them in there one of them gives me a URL error.  Here is the genre function in python.

"test()">.

```
      @app.route("/recommend/genre/<seed_genres>")
      def recommend_two(seed_genres):

endpoint_url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations?"
limit=2
market="US"
#seed_genres="indie"
target_danceability=0.9
combo = ""
q=drake&type=artist&limit=5'
query = f'{endpoint_url}limit={limit}&market={market}&seed_genres=.
{seed_genres}&target_danceability={target_danceability}'
token = getAccessToken(clientID, clientSecret)
response =requests.get(query,
headers={"Content-Type":"application/json",
            "Authorization":"Bearer " + token})
    
json_response = response.json()
head_one = "<h1/>"
head_two = "</h2"
for i in json_response['tracks']:
    combo += (f"\"{i['name']}\" by {i['artists'][0]['name']}")
return (head_one+combo+head_two)
```

Comment: You'll need to say what you mean by "these submissions" - you have not provided any sample code so no one can help to debug your problem.

Comment: I see a single form and a single submission button above. Could you please post the other one?